# Can anyone help me to find the mistake of this code (URI 1047)?

Tags: c

Uri 1047 (Game time with Minutes)

Can anyone help me, I don't see any mistake in my code. But when I submit it to URI it's showing wrong ans. But what's wrong in my code?

[image]

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int h1, h2, m1, m2, start, end, h, m, X;

    scanf ("%d%d%d%d", &h1, &m1, &h2, &m2);

    if (h1 > h2) {
        h2 = h2 + 24;
    }
    
    start = (h1 * 60) + m1;
    end = (h2 * 60) + m2;

    X = end - start;

    h = X / 60;
    m = X % 60;

    if (X == 0) {
        printf ("O JOGO DUROU 24 HORA(S) E 0 MINUTO(S)\n");
    }
    else {
        printf ("O JOGO DUROU %d HORA(S) E %d MINUTO(S)\n", h, m);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is your input?

Comment: According to the question, I've tested all kinds of input samples, like - (7 7 7 7, 15 20 13 40). But in every test case, I get the correct output.

Comment: You cannot use `scanf()` correctly unless you **check the return** to confirm all requested conversions succeeded or whether a *matching-failure* or *input-failure* occurred. Blindly using the result without checking the return invites undefined behavior.

Comment: "Uri 1047 (Game time with Minutes)" Is that supposed to mean anything for us? (There is no URI mentioned anyway)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. I am new at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
if(h1 > h2 || ( h1 == h2 && m1 >= m2 ) ) {
```

In the (edge) case of
start: 15:20
end: 15:15
your conditional would not recognise elapsed time of 23:55...

Here's a more compact version...

```
void main() {
    int h1, h2, m1, m2;

    scanf( "%d%d%d%d", &h1, &m1, &h2, &m2 );

    int start = (h1 * 60) + m1;
    int end = (h2 * 60) + m2;

    if( start >= end )
        end += 24 * 60;

    int X = end - start;
    int h = X / 60;
    int m = X % 60;

    printf("O JOGO DUROU %d HORA(S) E %d MINUTO(S)\n", h, m);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. After your comment, I thought about the logic and I've corrected my previous code's condition. The best part is when I submitted my code it is accepted. You pointed out my mistake to me. I was trying this problem for many days. Thank you.